# Window is too small and can't be resized

Tags: windows, git

Windows 8 - When I try to stretch the window it just jumps to the left side of the screen and still only partially shows the words or code on the left side of the git bash window.

Comment: please check mark next to my answer if that helped you

Comment: Retitled to try and avoid closure.  Question is valid, text used for the question was not.

Comment: remember jack it's 10 mins before one can accept. :)

Comment: Sorry, Usually new user see the answer but never click on check mark. :(

Comment: @Jack it's rather pointless, this question has a high chance of being deleted soon anyways. You could argue that it's on-topic because it's related to a programming tool, but that's going to be a rather weak argument for a question that's essentially "How do I resize a terminal window?".

Comment: no, please i will loose my reputation points :(

Answer (score 7):

Do the following:

click on top left then click on properties

[image: First Step]

do these settings on windows

[image: Second Steps]

then close and open git bash